# Dart - How to ignore \ operator inside string

Tags: string, dart

So, I have the question of how to ignore \ operator inside the string in dart. I want to get a sample string "abcde\fg\hijk" without taking this as an operator. Now I am getting something like that "abcdefghijk" (without backslashes, I don't want that )

Comment: I am getting image path from api, so it is important to have the same path.
I want to get: https:\/\/www.scorebat.com\/og\/m\/og972501.jpeg
What I get: https://www.scorebat.com/og/m/og972501.jpeg

Comment: Use double slashes as people has suggested or make it a raw string like: `r"abcde\fg\hijk"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a double slash: `'abcde\\fg\\hijk'`

Comment: I am getting this string from api, is there any other way?

Comment: Could you update the post with the exact response you get from the api.

Comment: @MateuszCz If you are getting the string from an API then it is already encoded to include the backslashes as characters. Escaping backslashes are just a compiler tool for string literals, they don't affect all forms of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use double backslash `\\`. Like:

```
"abcde\\fg\\hijk"
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have to escape the \ like:
`"abcde\\fg\\hijk"`